# Python float precision float

Tags: python, floating-point, double, precision

I need to implement a Dynamic Programming algorithm to solve the Traveling Salesman problem in time that beats Brute Force Search for computing distances between points. For this I need to index subproblems by size and the value of each subproblem will be a float (the length of the tour). However holding the array in memory will take about 6GB RAM if I use python floats (which actually have double precision) and so to try and halve that amount (I only have 4GB RAM) I will need to use single precision floats. However I do not know how I can get single precision floats in Python (I am using Python 3). Could someone please tell me where I can find them (I was not able to find much on this on the internet). Thanks.

**EDIT**: I notice that numpy also has a float16 type which will allow for even more memory savings. The distances between points are around 10000 and there are 25 unique points and my answer needs to be to the nearest integer. Will float16 provide enought accuracy or do I need to use float32?

Comment: @MarkDickinson. Thanks, this has helped my memory usage to go down to just over 1GB which means that my solution is feasible at least in terms of space. I am having a bit of trouble at getting to grips with the numpy array as the syntax is different from a python list but I am learning fast!

Comment: Yes, there's definitely a learning curve.  For large data, the results tend to be worth it, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a first step, you should use a [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) array to store your data instead of a Python list.

As you correctly observe, a Python float uses double precision internally, and the double-precision *value* underlying a Python float can be represented in 8 bytes. But on a 64-bit machine, with the CPython reference implementation of Python, a Python `float` *object* takes a full 24 bytes of memory: 8 bytes for the underlying double-precision value, 8 bytes for a pointer to the object type, and 8 bytes for a reference count (used for garbage collection).  There's no equivalent of Java's "primitive" types or .NET's "value" types in Python - everything is boxed.  That makes the language semantics simpler, but means that objects tend to be fatter.

Now if we're creating a Python *list* of `float` objects, there's the added overhead of the list itself: one 8-byte object pointer per Python `float` (still assuming a 64-bit machine here).  So in general, a list of `n` Python `float` objects is going to cost you over `32n` bytes of memory. On a 32-bit machine, things are a little better, but not much: our `float` objects are going to take 16 bytes each, and with the list pointers we'll be using `20n` bytes of memory for a list of `float`s of length `n`. (Caveat: this analysis doesn't quite work in the case that your list refers to the *same* Python `float` object from multiple list indices, but that's not a particularly common case.)

In contrast, a NumPy array of `n` double-precision floats (using NumPy's `float64` dtype) stores its data in "packed" format in a single data block of `8n` bytes, so allowing for the array metadata the total memory requirement will be a little over `8n` bytes.

Conclusion: just by switching from a Python list to a NumPy array you'll reduce your memory needs by about a factor of 4. If that's still not enough, then it might make sense to consider reducing precision from double to single precision (NumPy's `float32` dtype), if that's consistent with your accuracy needs.  NumPy's `float16` datatype takes only 2 bytes per float, but records only about 3 decimal digits of precision; I suspect that it's going to be close to useless for the application you describe.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the `c_float` type from the `ctypes` standard library.  Alternatively, if you are capable of installing additional packages you might try the `numpy` package.  It includes the `float32` type.

Comment: I already have numpy installed (it came with the python distribution I installed) but have never used it. Well, I guess there is a first time for everything!

Comment: Using `c_float` would cause much more harm than good: a `c_float` object is much bigger than a regular Python `float`.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  My recommendations should have been swapped as numpy would be my first choice anyway.